# Query to check if record has existed for more than X hours

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Here's a sample data.

```
ID | Date
---------
1  | 4/21/2015 11:00:00 AM
1  | 4/21/2015 01:00:00 PM
```

Let's say it's currently 2 PM, I need to query ID number 1 only if the time difference between the Column `Date` and `Now` is >= 2 hours.

```
Select ID from Table where datediff(hour, Date, getdate()) >= 2 and ID = '1'
```

Now this query would return the 1st record with the 11 AM time, but I want to ignore other records and just check if the latest record has existed for 2 or more hours. How should I change my query so that I will not get any results if the current time is 2 PM and my last record is 1 PM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select  id, max(date) as date
from Table
where id = 1
group by id
having datediff(hh, max(date), getdate()) >= 2
```

Remove `where` clause and you will get all ids that satisfy condidion.

Answer (score 0):

Use `MAX` with `GROUP BY` to get the latest date for an id and then check if it is greater than 2 hours. Something like this.

```
SELECT ID,Date
FROM
(Select ID,MAX(Date) Date 
from Table 
GROUP BY ID
)T
where datediff(hour, Date, getdate()) >= 2 and ID = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Always be aware of exactly what information is being returned from a function. The DateDiff function returns the number of unit boundaries that are between the two time arguments. An hour boundary, for instance, is when the minutes, seconds and fractional seconds are zero: hh:00:00.000. So the value returned can be very misleading:

```
select  DateDiff( hh, '2015-01-01 12:59:59', '2015-01-01 14:00:00' ) as Short,
        DateDiff( hh, '2015-01-01 12:00:00', '2015-01-01 14:59:59' ) as Long
```

The answer is 2 hours in both cases but the actual difference between the two dates is one hour and one second in the first case and one second shy of three hours in the second case. But the intervals touch the same two hour boundaries, one at 13:00 exactly and one at 14:00 exactly.

If you want to get the values that are within two hours *exactly*, then use the DateAdd function:

```
select  ID, Max( date ) as Date
from    Table
where   ID = 1
group by ID
having  Max( date) <= DateAdd( hh, -2, GetDate());
```

Now if a date is an hour and 59 minutes ago, it will not be seen but the one two hours and one second ago will be seen, no matter where the hour boundaries are.